# Toggling visibility between two HTML elements in same space

Tags: javascript, html, layout, visibility

I have two HTML elements that share the same space- when one is visible, the other should not be.  However, if I just set the other's visibility to 'hidden', it still occupies space in the display hierarchy, whereas I want it to go away.  I don't want to remove the reference entirely, though, as I need to be able to toggle between the two elements.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `display:none`, not `visibility:hidden`

Comment: and display:block to turn visible again